# Static-storage-duration object uniquness guaranties when dynamically loaded from multiple libraries

Tags: c, linux, unix, shared-libraries, dlopen

Imagine that there is a shared library `S`, there are shared libraries `A` and `B`, and an executable `C`. `A` and `B` are linked against `S`. `C` is not linked against `A` and `B`, instead `C` dynamically loads `A` and `B` via `dlopen`. `S` has a static-storage-duration object `O` with external linkage that is used inside `A` and `B`.

I know that the linker guaranties the uniqueness of static objects with external linkage, for example, if `C` would be linked against `A` and `B` then `O` will be unique, but I am not sure about the dynamic library loading.

Will the dynamically loaded libraries `A` and `B` share the same memory of object `O`, or it will be two separately allocated objects `O`? If the object `O` is shared, then loading `A`, modifying object `O`, loading `B` should work find, i.e. `B` will see the changes to the object `O`?

Comment: "*if `C` would be linked against `A` and `B` then `O` will be unique*" -- I very much doubt that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no difference whether you let the program loader load the dynamically shared object or you do it explicitly, e.g. with `dlopen()` on a *nix system. The same rules apply.

But in both cases, you will have the same object instance in your `A` and `B`. This is because with `C` linking both of them, both are **in the same process**. The dynamic linker just ensures that every process gets its own copy of static objects (while still all processes might share the code segment).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. One thing just struck me, what if the object `O` is inside `A` and `B`, so there is no library `S`, `O` is just inside a static archive that is linked to both `A` and `B`. Will the loader figure it to be the only one object in `C`?

Comment: Huh? If you statically link some data, it becomes part of the module it's linked to. so your `O` in `A` is something different than your `O` in `B`.